React Native WebView not Recording Audio
I have a URL that is recording the audio of the user but when I open that URL in my webview and try to record audio it does not record the audio of the user.
I have already taken permissions for both audio and external storage.
how to solve this issue?
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  BackHandler,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
  const webviewRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      () => {
        if (webviewRef.current) {
          // webviewRef.current.goBack();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    );

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
      ]).then(result => {
        if (result['android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'] !== 'granted') {
          console.log('Microphone permission denied');
        }
      });
    }

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        source={{uri: 'myURL(Private'}}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;

I cant show URL because it is private
